# Magento product list grid mode how to remove toolbars?

Tags: magento-1.7, static-block

I want to show 20 products on my homepage without any toolbar at the top or bottom.

Currently I have this block, which shows a toolbar:

`{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" category_id="26" product_count="20" show_items="4"
is_responsive="1" is_random="0" hide_button="0" block_name="X"
template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

How do disable the toolbars at the top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way without affecting the lists on the category pages is to make a copy of `list.phtml`, rename it to, for example, `homelist.phtml` and comment out

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

Which is located in the top and bottom of your phtml file.

Now all you need to do is change the template attribute to point to this new file

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" category_id="26" product_count="20" show_items="4" is_responsive="1" is_random="0" hide_button="0" block_name="X" template="catalog/product/homelist.phtml"}}
```

Comment: To bad this is not an standard option.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Ultimo theme. In version 1.10.4 of that theme you can remove the toolbars by adding `hide_toolbar='1'`

```
{{block hide_toolbar="1" ...etc... }}
```

See:

- In the Ultimo User Guide, see section "6.1.3.C Products grid".
- Theme: http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798